# date string format binding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

I am trying to get date format as "MM/dd/yyyy", however, the current date format is coming with time too, I tried to format it with the following codes, however it is not changing, could you please correct me as follows:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Bill Date" Binding="{Binding BillDate, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}" Width="90" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

and

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bill Date" Width="90">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding BillDate}" ContentStringFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

my property code is as follows:

```
Property BillDate As Date
    Get
        Return _BillDate
    End Get
    Set(Value As Date)
        If Not _BillDate = Value Then
            _BillDate = Value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BillDate")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

I dont want to correct at property level, I only want to display the format at XAML, the above format is not working although it is correct to my knowledge.

EDIT:
After many trails and few experients, I came to know that the solution is not building any new code.  So, the problem now is - new, modified xaml is not getting built.  Could you please help me in this.

Comment: Your update is confusing, what is failing? Is it the conversion of date to mm/dd/yyyy or a parse failure? It sounds like you have added properties to items which are not available. So, where is it failing?

Comment: I think he means that DevStudio is not building the XAML when he mods it. @surpavan: Are you definitely editing the correct XAML file? Did you make a duplicate somewhere when playing around?

Comment: I am closing the question, I came to know the issue, the .dll file got locked, the VS testing service did not close after run. I restarted the PC and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
"{Binding BillDate, StringFormat=d}"
```

which should give you month/day/year as output.

## Update

The control `Label`'s `Content` property is of type object and does not apply formatting like a string does. Here are your options,

Use the [ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) property on the label:

```
<Label ContentStringFormat="d">
    <system:DateTime>2015/3/4 13:6:55</system:DateTime>
</Label>
```

Or the `TextBox` control, the `Text` property is a string and it takes formatting parameters.

Comment: @surpavan I updated my post. Either create converter for the label or change to use a `TextBox` control. See why above.

Comment: Thank you. Instead of creating a converter class, it is easy to create a readonly property to return in string format.  And the control I am using is a datagridtextcolumn, so string format should work.

Answer (score 3):

The type of your property should be [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), not `Date`:

```
Property BillDate As DateTime
    ...
End Property
```

Then this works:

```
<Label Content="{Binding BillDate}" ContentStringFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

But you might perhaps better use a TextBlock instead of a Label:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BillDate, StringFormat=MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
```

Comment: Tried it now, it is still the same result, getting with time still, not able to figure out why :(.